# Display table data without user auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm studying event message board. I can display table data by every Users own post. however I would like to display All post too. I wrote this as $tasksall but it didn't work. Could someone teach me what is wrong?

**AController.php**

```php
public function index()
{

    $tasks = Auth::user()
        ->tasks()
        ->orderBy('is_complete')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->paginate(5);

    $tasksall =
        ->tasks()
        ->orderBy('is_complete')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at')
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks, 'tasksall' => $tasksall
    ]);
}
```

**Task.php** (model)

```php
class Task extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'is_complete' => 'boolean',
    ];


    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'is_complete',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**AController.php**  I add this code

```php
 public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Task');
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->id . ':'/ $this->person->name.')';
    }
```

**index.blade.php**  I add this code

```php
{{ $task2->getData() }}
```

Comment: What isn't working? what errors are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a query to get all the task using eloquent to get all the tasks.

```php
$tasksall = Task::all();
```

Have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) link.

Also for you case I think the problem is you are getting task from the `User` model so you $task will contain only task related to that particular user as you have a `belongsTo` relation of task with user.

For Your case to get `name` of `User` from `task`.

//Task model

```php
class Task {

  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Then you can query like this in your controller.

```php
$task = Task::find($id);

$name = $task->user->name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! I appreciate quick answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mr.InvincibleElf   I studyed belongsTo. I would like to display who wrote. I wrote like this. but it didn't worked. Could you help me little more please?

Comment: Mr.InvincibleElf I feel like my added code are messy but I couldn't find a way to include this add part...

Comment: @blueink If you want to get the `name` of the `User` from the task. You can get it by using eloquent. Eloquent fetches user related to `task` provided that you have declared relationship `Task` model. In your controller, $this is pointing to `Acontroller` object not the `Task` model and should declare relationship in your model not the controller.

Comment: Hi @InvincibleElf I appreciate answering me. Thank you so much. I tryed your code then I got this meesage "Undefined variable: id".  I use this code from this gentleman's website  https://medium.com/@brice_hartmann/building-a-user-based-task-list-application-in-laravel-eff4a07e2688  . I thoguht if you see the whole image of code helps what my code are problem.

Comment: I have two question. one is I don't need to to put "return"  $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id'); ?  Second is I would like to know the code of return of " public function index()" Here is my current code --->  return view('tasks', [
            'tasks' => $tasks, 'tasksall' => $tasksall, 'name' => $name
        ]); I feel something wrong there are 3 variables. I feel this is stragen and not handy to get a data at blade file as foreach loop.

Comment: @bluelink I think you need to. I just edited my answer. The answer to your second question the index() method in controller is generally used to get listing of the resources. Usual practice is to bind this method with get request in your api.php or web.php  file inside routes folder. 
You need to read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) to understand more about routing.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Still it didin't work I think I need to study basic. to adjust this code is very study for me but its difficult for me current skill. I wiil take a time and try. Thank you so much all of your help.